# Updating state with functions inside. Should we use It?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've watched a video with React best practices. The author said that updating state with functions inside is a best practice because if we write this statement two times, it would still work properly (example #2).
However, I can't understand, in which situations it helps us to avoid bugs. Maybe you have some examples...

```
export default function Counter({ initCount }) {
const [count, setCount] = useState(initCount);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
}, [count]);

const incrementCount = () => {
    // example #1
    // setCount(count + 1);
    // setCount(count + 1);
    // count was incremented by 1

    // example #2
    setCount((currCount) => currCount + 1);
    setCount((currCount) => currCount + 1);
    // count was incremented by 2, as expected
};

const decrementCount = () => {
    setCount((currCount) => currCount - 1);
    setCount((currCount) => currCount - 1);
};

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={decrementCount}>-</button>
        {count}
        <button onClick={incrementCount}>+</button>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-solomon-7tm62?file=/src/App.js:345-349) that demonstrates the difference. If the new state depends on the previous state, like incrementing a counter, then pass a function to the state setter function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating state using function inside only if I need to avoid unnecessary dependency in `useEffect` or `useCallback`
For example:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
   // useEffect depends on count now and we have to add `count` to dependency list
  setCount(count + 1)
}, [count]);


useEffect(() => {
  // no dependencies
  setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1) 
}, [])
```

So I think you should use the function for setState only if your changes depend on previous value of state